# Cordova Keyboard Plugin doesn't work in ionic View

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic-view

I've been trying to find an answer why the cordova keyboard plugin doesn't work in ionic view.

In the [documentation](http://docs.ionic.io/v1.0/docs/view-usage) it says it supports version 1.0.3.. The updated version is 1.0.4. I suspect that's the reason why the keyboard plugin doesn't work in ionic view. How can I downgrade to 1.0.3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realize this isn't a direct answer to your question, but...

Personally, I've found Ionic View, while a cool idea, to be mostly just a tool for basic previews. I've noticed all sorts of things don't work within Ionic View, such as overridden back button behavior, rendering inconsistencies, Crosswalk issues, etc.

I've done comparisons of Ionic View rendering directly with running the app on a device (using `ionic run`) and it very often has differences, even with minimally complex apps. That, to me, is unacceptable in a situation where you need valid prototypes. I previously wasted a lot of time trying to fix some issues that I found out were actually caused by Ionic View. I use the Cordova Keyboard plugin in one of my apps, and I was having issues with the event detection within Ionic View. Those issues didn't happen when I ran the app directly on my devices.

I've since switched to using [Google Play Staged Rollouts](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213?hl=en) to alpha/beta test my Ionic apps with multiple people/groups. Changes might not be reflected immediately (since updates need approval), but it will be exactly as the app is going to behave, and that might be the most important consideration of all.

However, if you're absolutely set on using Ionic View, you might consider filing this as an issue [on their GitHub page](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-view-issues/issues).

Comment: i ended up just getting a macbook  next day.. I just recently started doing ionic to develop for iOS hard to test without a mac.. Thanks!